# Unable to add list, REACT

Tags: reactjs, typescript, list, frontend, render

I am facing an issue while trying to update my list soon I click on elements from form. My intend is to get the elements added in list from selected elements of form. I have pasted my source code here.

```
APP.TSX

import { useState } from "react";
import StudentGradingEvaluationForm from "./assets/Components/StudentGradingEvaluationForm";
import { studentFormData } from "./assets/Components/StudentGradingEvaluationForm";
import GPACalculator from "./assets/Components/GPACalculator";
import CourseListwithGPA from "./assets/Components/CourseListwithGPA";

const App = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState<studentFormData | null>(null);
  const [isFormSubmitted, setFormSubmitted] = useState(true);
  const [messageAppear, setMessageAppear] = useState(false);
  const [gpa, setGpa] = useState<number>(0);
  const [gpaList, setGpaList] = useState([
    { id: 1, course: "", number: 0, gpa: 0 },
  ]);

  const handleFormSubmit = (data: studentFormData) => {
    if (data) {
      setFormData(data);
      setMessageAppear(true);
      // setFormSubmitted(true);
    }
  };
  const resetForm = () => {
    setFormData(null);
    setFormSubmitted(false);
  };

  const handleGpa = (gpa: number) => {
    setGpa(gpa);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <h1>Student Grading Evaluation Form</h1>
      </div>
      {isFormSubmitted && (
        <>
          <StudentGradingEvaluationForm onSubmit={handleFormSubmit} />
        </>
      )}
      {messageAppear && (
        <div className="mt-3">
          <p>Form submitted successfully</p>
          <button onClick={resetForm} className="btn btn-outline-danger">
            Reset Form
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
      {formData && formData.course && (
        <>
          <GPACalculator
            name={formData.name}
            course={formData.course}
            number={formData.number}
          />
          <CourseListwithGPA
            students = {(student) => setGpaList([...students, {id: student.id, course: student.course, number: student.number, gpa: student.gpa}])}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
GPACalculator.tsx

interface Props {
  name: string;
  course: string;
  number: number;
}

const GPACalculator = ({ name, course, number }: Props) => {
  const calculateGPA = () => {
    if (number < 100 && number >= 80) return "4.0";
    else if (number < 80 && number >= 65) return "3.5";
    else if (number < 65 && number >= 55) return "3.0";
    else if (number < 55 && number >= 40) return "2.0";
    else return "FAIL";
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>GPA Calculator Result for {name}</h2>
      <p>Course: {course}</p>
      <p>Number: {number}</p>
      <p>GPA: {calculateGPA()}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GPACalculator;
```

```
StudentGradingEvaluationForm.tsx

import { z } from "zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import courses from "./Courses";

interface Props {
  onSubmit: (data: studentFormData) => void;
}

const schema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(3),
  course: z.enum(courses),
  number: z.number().int().positive().max(100),
});

export type studentFormData = z.infer<typeof schema>;

const StudentGradingEvaluationForm = ({ onSubmit }: Props) => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<studentFormData>({
    resolver: zodResolver(schema),
  });
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">
          Name of Student
        </label>
        <input
          {...register("name")}
          id="name"
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
        />
      </div>
      {errors.name && <p className="text-danger">{errors.name.message}</p>}
      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="course" className="form-label">
          Select Course
        </label>
        <select {...register("course")} id="course" className="form-select">
          <option value="none">Select a course</option>
          {courses.map((course, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={course}>
              {course}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        {errors.course && (
          <p className="text-danger">{errors.course.message}</p>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="number" className="form-label">
          Number
        </label>
        <input
          {...register("number", { valueAsNumber: true })}
          id="number"
          type="number"
          className="form-control"
        />
      </div>
      {errors.number && <p className="text-danger">{errors.number.message}</p>}
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default StudentGradingEvaluationForm;
```

```
CourseListwithGPA.tsx

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

interface StudentInfo {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  course: string;
  number: number;
}

interface StudentInfoWithGPA extends StudentInfo {
  gpa: number;
}

interface Props {
  students: (data: StudentInfoWithGPA) => void;
}

const CourseListwithGPA = ({ students }: Props) => {
  const [gpa, setGpa] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const calculatedGPA = calculateGPA();
    const newGpa = parseFloat(calculatedGPA[0]);
    if (newGpa !== parseFloat(gpa)) {
      setGpa(calculatedGPA.join(", "));
      // Replace onGpaChange with the function you want to call when the GPA changes
      // onGpaChange("", 0, newGpa);
      console.log("GPA changed to:", newGpa);
    }
  }, [students, gpa]);

  const calculateGPA = () => {
    return students.map((student) => {
      if (student.number < 100 && student.number >= 80) return "4.0";
      else if (student.number < 80 && student.number >= 65) return "3.5";
      else if (student.number < 65 && student.number >= 55) return "3.0";
      else if (student.number < 55 && student.number >= 40) return "2.0";
      else return "FAIL";
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="mb-3">
        <h1>Report Card of {students.map((student) => student.name)}</h1>
      </div>
      <table className="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Name of Course</td>
            <td>Marks Obtained</td>
            <td>GPA</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {students.map((student) => (
            <tr key={student.id}>
              <td>{student.course}</td>
              <td>{student.number}</td>
              <td>{gpa}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

export default CourseListwithGPA;
```

```
Courses.ts


const courses = [
  "Mechanics of Materials - I",
  "Fluid Dynamics - I",
  "Ordinary Differential Equations",
  "Thermodynamics - II",
  "Basic Electrical and Electronics Engineering",
] as const;

export default courses;
```

My intention is to showcase all courses with GPA in a list. For reference, i have added Screenshot.[image]

As you can see, Objects are remaining empty. I need someone to tweak my code so that whenever I update my form, it gets added in list.

But I am unable to do so. I am using following dependencies:

npm create vite@4.1.0
npm i bootstrap
npm i zod@3.20.6
npm i react-hook-form@7.43
npm i @hookform/resolvers@2.9.11

Comment: It's not really clear to me what issue you are trying to solve and there's way too much code here for me to understand what's going on. Would you please try to [focus on creating a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that only includes the parts most relevant to your issue? It'd also help if you provide some examples of what information you expect to get and where where, as well as what you've already tried and why you think those approaches aren't working.

Comment: @Shaavin I have edited my post and added Screenshot. I hope this is now more concise and clear.

Comment: Again, there is far too much code here for anyone to be able to help you. I can guess at what you're trying to accomplish, but your description of the problem is too short to understand where the perceived issue is. Please [carefully review the Stack Overflow how to ask help guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your post - especially focusing on the _Introduce the problem before you post any code_ and _Help others reproduce the problem_ sections. Just copy-pasting your entire program and adding screenshots isn't enough for us to understand.